# Slope between two points in X,Y,Z coordinate system

Tags: java, syntax, lines

I took a course in Java at University 2 years ago, and now I have to create a program where I type in 2 sets of coordinates, and the program will create a 3-D graph of a line between the two points, as well as give the slope and angle between the two points.  I've been trying to get familiar with the Java syntax, but I have to complete the program by tomorrow so I figured I would ask for help.  I've put together code, but it isn't in Java's syntax (most of it isn't anyways) and I need help converting it to code that will work.  I'm using double for my variables because the points the user enters can be decimals.  The only coordinates the user will input are x, and y for both points, the z coordinates are set at z1 = 0 and z2 = 1.  The way I have put the variables together, it assumes the z coordinate extends out of the screen, and the y coordinate plane extends vertically.

Again, I'm familiar with general coding terms, but as I've looked around on the internet i see things like `import java.util.*` and that stuff doesn't make sense to me as to how it owuld apply to my program.

Any help is appreciated!

P.S. if you want me to add comments as to what certain things mean, let me know.  i.e. `create.cube` is a syntax I made up, but I want the computer to create a window that will show a cube with the coordinates I have set.

```
package slope;

public class Slope1 {
double xvar;
double yvar;
double zvar;

xvar x1 = new xvar;
xvar x2 = new xvar;

yvar y1 = new yvar;
yvar y2 = new yvar;

zvar z1 = new zvar;
zvar z2 = new zvar;

    public static void main(String[]args){
        z1 = 0;
        z2 = 1;

        get.x1 from user
            if(x1>9 or x1<-9){
                System.out.println("Please choose values within range")
            }
        get.x2 from user
        if(x2>9 or x2<-9){
            System.out.println("Please choose values within range")
        }
        get.y1 from user
        if(y1>12 or y2<-12){
            System.out.println("Please choose values within range")
        }
        get.y2 from user
        if(y1>12 or y2<-12){
            System.out.println("Please choose values within range")
        }

        slope1 = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
        angle1 = arctan(slope1);
        distance1 = (y2-y1)/sin(angle1);

        slopeFinal = 1/distance1;
        angleFinal = arctan(slopeFinal);

        System.out.println("Your Slope is " + slopeFinal);
        System.out.println("Angle of entry is " + angleFinal);
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        create.cube;
        xlength cube = -9 to 9;
        ylength cube = -12 to 12;
        zlenght cube = 0 to 12

        cube x origin at x=0;
        cube y origin at y=0;
        cube z origin at z=0;

        draw line from (x1,y1,z1) to (x2,y2,z2) in cube;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you really who you claim to be in your profile? Your post seems to indicate otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense at all and has many syntax errors.

```
create.cube;
xlength cube = -9 to 9;
ylength cube = -12 to 12;
zlenght cube = 0 to 12

cube x origin at x=0;
cube y origin at y=0;
cube z origin at z=0;
```

None of the above are valid statements in java.

You might wanna study java once again and look up gui programming with java as well. below is a link to get you started.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming

Comment: Yea, I know it doesn't make sense, it is all pseudo code.  I indicated as much in my question.  I need help in figuring out how to create the cube.  I wanted to show you that I was thinking and tried to put my idea into words.  Sorry about that.